# Getting an error when trying to run rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting the following error when i try the command rake db:migrate

```
> NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be
> removed on or after 2011-11-01. Gem.source_index called from
> /home/hilarl/workspace/depot/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21.
> NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#initialize is deprecated with no replacement.
> It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01. Gem::SourceIndex#initialize
> called from
> /home/hilarl/workspace/depot/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:100.
> NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use
> Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
> Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from
> /home/hilarl/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
> NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use
> Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
> Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from
> /home/hilarl/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
> NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use
> Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
> Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from
> /home/hilarl/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
> NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use
> Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
> Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from
> /home/hilarl/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
> NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use
> Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
> Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from
> /home/hilarl/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
> NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use
> Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
> Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from
> /home/hilarl/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
> WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.  Please use 'require
> 'rdoc/task' (in RDoc 2.4.2+)' instead.
>     at /home/hilarl/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb
> rake aborted! can't activate activesupport-3.2.3, already activated
> activesupport-2.3.14
> 
> (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Any idea why this is happening? i am using ubuntu, have ruby 1.9.3-p194 and rails 2.3.14 installed on my system and using sqlite3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what versions of rails you have installed:

```
$ gem list rails

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rails (3.2.3, 2.3.14)
```

You should have multiple of them like I do here 3.2.3 and 2.3.14

afterwards uninstall the ones you dont need with:

```
$ gem uninstall rails -v2.3.14
Remove executables:
    rails

in addition to the gem? [Yn]  Y
Removing rails
Successfully uninstalled rails-2.3.14
```

at the end you should have just one version of rails:

```
$ gem list rails

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rails (3.2.3)
```

Comment: strange, i am getting an empty list, but i definitely have rails intalled


hilarl@isa009:~/workspace/depot$ gem list rails

*** LOCAL GEMS ***


hilarl@isa009:~/workspace/depot$

Comment: ok it worked, had to reinstall the rails gem for some reason. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Can you trying running

`bundle exec rake db:migrate`

You can have different versions of the same gem installed in your system - and so  `bundle exec <command>`  uses the gem whose version is tied with your projects Gemfile (search for your gem in the Gemfile.lock file to see which version is being used).

A better practice would be to create gemsets to package select versions of gems which will be activated based on the project in context.

http://bcardarella.com/post/699582642/rvm-gemsets-bundler-awesome

Comment: when i try that i am getting 'Could not locate Gemfile'